# Associating C# Web application code in an SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS package and don’t have enough knowledge of the same. Below are some of my requirements:

1. I have a C# web application which reads data from an excel file, and we just need to give the folder path and its reads all excel files data in that folder.
2. Then I am putting that data in sql database.
3. I want to associate this C# web application code with an SSIS Package.
4. Can anyone give me steps how to create an SSIS package and how to associate this package with the c# code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do by following steps.
1. Create SSIS package - Please do search how to create SSIS package.
2. Host web application with dynamic loading package there you can update all configuration parameters dynamicaly.
3. I hope folder you mentioned in the server, if not then it has to be

go through this - [Programatically load SSIS package configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707901/programatically-load-ssis-package-configurations)

please let me know if you need further help